# Do all hover states need a link?

Tags: css

Sorry, may seem like a silly question but just wanted to see if my theory was correct.

Is it possible to have a hover state on a div which isn't a button or a link.. essentially the client has asked for the 3 images here (http://www.origami-brand.com/bgb/about-us/) to not have a 'hand icon' when you hover over.

However, after combing through the plugins code, I can't find any links to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the question fully, but you can use the [cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/cursor?v=control) property to change what the cursor looks like.

```
.vc_column_container { cursor: default; }
```

Comment: @DylanGarrod, if you consider your question answered, please mark one of the answers as "accepted" to let other people know that your problem has been solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your question at first, but

1.) No, they don't you can use hover rules on other elements too

2.) You can use the `cursor` parameter and set it to `default`on the hover state to avoid the pointer:

```css
.x {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
background: url(http://placehold.it/300x200/fa0);
}
.x:hover {
background: url(http://placehold.it/300x200/0af);
cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help